# TestNg test with multiple Factory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

With reference to my previous question, 
"[Executing multiple test sequentially with different parameters testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581228/executing-multiple-test-sequentially-with-different-parameters-testng)"

The current difficulty I am facing is, I want to execute a testNg test class sequentially for different multiple parameter with different parameter to be precise

### Test-1 with data: laptop, lg

### Test-2 with data: laptop, Samsung

### Test-3 with data: laptop, Toshiba

### Test-1 with data: TV, Lg

### Test-2 with data: TV, Samsung

### Test-3 with data: TV, Toshiba

Comment: There is a bit change in the scenario actually what we are actually trying is

Test-1 with data: laptop, lg

Test-2 with data: laptop, lg

Test-3 with data: laptop, lg

Test-1 with data: laptop, Samsung

Test-2 with data: laptop, Samsung

Test-3 with data: laptop, Samsung


Test-1 with data: TV, Lg

Test-2 with data: TV, lg

Test-3 with data: TV, lg

Test-1 with data: TV, Samsung

Test-2 with data: TV, Samsung

Test-3 with data: TV, Samsung

Comment: Does it mean you want to run first all the tests against first combination of test data and again all the tests against second combination of test data?

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar yes I want to execute all this in one go and sequentially 

Test-1 with data: laptop, lg 
--
Test-2 with data: laptop, lg 
---
Test-3 with data: laptop, lg 
---
Test-1 with data: laptop, Samsung 
---
Test-2 with data: laptop, Samsung 
---
Test-3 with data: laptop, Samsung 
---
Test-1 with data: TV, Lg 
---
Test-2 with data: TV, lg 
---
Test-3 with data: TV, lg 
---
Test-1 with data: TV, Samsung
--- 
Test-2 with data: TV, Samsung 
---
Test-3 with data: TV, Samsung

Comment: I am new to selenium. Even I want to achieve the above said scenario. Basically a scenario can be in multiple classes[as project is big I cannot put all test cases in single class]. I want to execute each scenario with each set of data. Meaning execute first scenario with first set of data then second & so on. I used dependsOnGroups in subsequent classes, parallel=false & group-by-instances, but still its executing 1st class with all set of data & then moving to next class. Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

A basic TestNG DataProvider does exactly what you are wanting to do.  You just need to create a simple TestNG project with a test method that references a DataProvider.

Comment: But if we use dataprovider then it does not execute in a sequence.

Comment: Yes, it will execute in sequence if you set the DataProvider to not use multi-threading.   Also, you have further control by being able to force the test suite to be single threaded as well.   Also, I think TestNG has a preserve-order flag (but it doesnt affect the Data provider).  Also, if these suggestions dont work for you, another way to force order is to split into separate tests and put each test in a separate `<test>` block in the testng.xml .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this? Is it not executing in sequence?

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "laptop", "Lg" },
   { "laptop", "Samsung"},
   { "laptop", "Toshiba"},
   { "TV", "Lg" },
   { "TV", "Samsung"},
   { "TV", "Toshiba"},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String device, String brand) {
 System.out.println(device + " " + brand);
}
```

Comment: for executing it sequentially I tried method mentioned in following 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581228/executing-multiple-test-sequentially-with-different-parameters-testng)

Current issue what I am facing is Mentioned in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

Well found a solution but not a perfect one. I am using the following code to get the above result, but the scenario here is that sometimes it executes in sequence but some times randomly. Following is the code snippet,

```
public class TestFactoryTest {

   public  static List<Object> addObject=new ArrayList<Object>();
   public static  List<String> sheetName=new ArrayList<String>();
   public static  List<Object> getworkbook=new ArrayList<Object>();
   public File folder = new File("D:\\ChannelSense");

   Object objArray[]=null;

   static
   {
          sheetName.add("Television");
          sheetName.add("Laptop");

   }

   @Factory(dataProvider="ExcelFiles")
   public Object[] runclass(String addObject1)
   {
          addObject=new ArrayList<>();
          System.out.println("addObject1>>"+addObject1);

          for(int i=0;i<sheetName.size();i++)
          {
           System.out.println("addObject1>>"+addObject1+">>"+sheetName.get(i));
           addObject.add(new TestMethod(addObject1,sheetName.get(i)));        
          }

          System.out.println("addObject.size;>>"+addObject.size());
          objArray=new Object[addObject.size()];
          for(int i=0;i<addObject.size();i++)
          {
                 objArray[i]=addObject.get(i);
          }
          return objArray;
   }

   @DataProvider(name="ExcelFiles")
   public Iterator<Object[]> passaddObject()
   {
          final File FolderName=folder;
          List<String> lst=new ArrayList<String>();
          List<Object[]> dataToBeReturned = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
          for(final File workbookname:FolderName.listFiles())
          {

                       lst.add(workbookname.getName()); 


          }
          for(String workbookname:lst)
          {
                 dataToBeReturned.add(new Object[]{workbookname});
          }
          return  dataToBeReturned.iterator();
   }

}
```

Output of the above code when I execute it 1st time then it gives,

```
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Laptops
File: LG.xlsx
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Television
File: LG.xlsx
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Television
File: Toshiba.xlsx
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Laptops
File: Toshiba.xlsx


In second execution it returns,

-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Laptops
File: LG.xlsx
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Television
File: Toshiba.xlsx
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Television
File: LG.xlsx
-----TestCase1-----
Product:  Laptops
File: Toshiba.xlsx
```

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite-A" verbose="1">
<test name="test" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="TestFactoryTest"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>`

Xml file used