# TestNG with 2 Testcase with data provider

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have question about TestNG. I have some dataset for testing, but I want to execute full cycle of test per data in the dataset. How can I do that?

This is my Code

```
@DataProvider(name = "login")
public static Object[][] usernamePassword() {
    // username, password, isSukses
    return new Object[][] { 
        { "coin", "coin123", true }, 
        { "coin", "coin", false },
        { "username", "password", false } };
}

 @Test(description = "Fill the Login Details", priority = 2)
public void FillLoginDetails(String user, String pass, boolean isSuccess) throws Exception {

    try {
        // Get the username element
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("uid"));
        username.sendKeys(user);

        // Get the password element
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pwd"));
        password.sendKeys(pass);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        TestNGResults.put("3", new Object[] { 2d, "Fill Login form data (Username/Password)",
                "Login details gets filled", "Pass" });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        TestNGResults.put("3",
                new Object[] { 2d, "Fill Login form data (Username/Password)", "Login form gets filled", "Fail" });
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}

@Test(description = "Perform Login", priority = 3)
public void doLogin() throws Exception {

    try {
        // Click on the Login button
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login-button"));
        login.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Assert the user login by checking the Online user
        WebElement onlineuser = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h3.paddedleft > strong.ng-binding"));
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals("Welcome, " + "coin", onlineuser.getText());
        TestNGResults.put("4",
                new Object[] { 3d, "Click Login and verify welcome message", "Login success", "Pass" });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TestNGResults.put("4",
                new Object[] { 3d, "Click Login and verify welcome message", "Login success", "Fail" });
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

how can test like this,

> Test priority 2 ( data 1 ),
>
> Test priority 3 ( data 1 ),
>
> ---
>
> Test priority 2 ( data 2 ),
>
> Test priority 3 ( data 2 ),
>
> ---
>
> Test priority 2 ( data 3 ),
>
> Test priority 3 ( data 3 ),

???

Comment: What you are getting result as of now,

Comment: @Rizqi Ahmad Fauzan: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above scenario with the Factory Concepts.But the test data needs to be moved to different class and need to do some modification in your test class.

Please check the below URL and you will get the clear idea.

http://fruzenshtein.com/testng-dataprovider-run-tests-sequentially/

[Executing multiple test sequentially with different parameters testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581228/executing-multiple-test-sequentially-with-different-parameters-testng)

### Create an instance variable for your paramterized data

```
String user; 
String pass;
boolean isSuccess;
```

### **Do the constructor Overloading with the above parameters and initialize the instance variable**

```
//Assumed the Class Name as LoginTest

LoginTest(String user, String pass, boolean isSuccess){
this.user=user;
this.pass=pass;
this.isSuccess=isSuccess;
}
```

### Create Another Class for the Data Provider

```
public class SampleFactory {

        @Factory(dataProvider="login")
        public Object[] createInstances((String userName, String password, boolean isSuccess) {
            return new Object[] {new LoginTest(userName, password,isSuccess)};
        }

        @DataProvider(name = "login")
        public static Object[][] usernamePassword() {
            // username, password, isSukses
            return new Object[][] { 
                { "coin", "coin123", true }, 
                { "coin", "coin", false },
                { "username", "password", false } };
        }

    }
```

### Configure and Run the TestNG XML

Add the SampleFactory Class alone in your testng xml and Run your test.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are missing dataProvider="login"

@Test(dataProvider="login", description = "Perform Login", priority = 3)